# Regex matching only numbers

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am having problems understanding what my regex in bash shell is doing exactly.

I have the string `abcde 12345 67890testing`. I want to extract `12345` from this string using `sed`.

However, using `sed -re 's/([0-9]+).*/\1/'` on the given string will give me `abcde 12345`.

Alternatively, using `sed -re 's/([\d]+).*/\1/'` would actually only extract `abcd`.

Am I wrong in assuming that the expression `[0-9]` and `[\d]` ONLY capture digits? I have no idea how `abcd` is being captured yet the string `67890` is not. Plus, I want to know why the space is being captured in my first query?

In addition, `sed -re 's/^.*([0-9]+).*/\1/'` gives me `0`. In this instance, I completely do not understand what the regex is doing. I'd thought that the expression `^.*[0-9]+` would only capture the first instance of a string of only numbers? However, it's matching only the last 0.

All in all, I'd like to understand how I am wrong about all these. And how the problem should be solved WITHOUT using [\s] in the regex to isolate the first string of numbers.

Comment: The issue is that your `sed` command is this: "On each line, find some digits followed by any number of characters, and replace that match with the digits." It's doing what's specified, which is to replace `12345 67890testing` with `12345`. Instead, you want to replace the initial match with nothing. Unfortunately, as far as I know there's no way to put a non-greedy `.*?` at the front of a `sed` expression, and inline Perl or Ruby might be a better option.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+).*/\1/g'  <<< "$s"
```

The above command means: find a sequence of number followed by something and replace it with only the numbers. So it matches *12345 67890testing* and replaces it with only *12345*.

The final string will be *abcd 12345*.

If you want to get only 12345 you should use grep.

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+ ' <<< "$s"
```

Or with sed you can use:

```
sed -E 's/[a-zA-Z ]*([0-9]+).*/\1/g'  <<< "$s"
```

This will drop the letters before the numbers

Comment: For my last attempt, is using the greedy expression `.*` eating into the rest of the string until it leaves only `0`? It seems impossible to use greedy expressions to remove the preceding `abcde` part of the problem then?

Comment: If you use .*([0-9]+).* it'll match only the last number because the + means 1 or more so it'll se the minimum. If you know exactly the length of the sequence of numbers you can use .*([0-9]{5}) .* There must be a space between the ) and the .

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/g' <<< "$s"
12345
```

OR else modifying your sed:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' <<< "$s"
12345
```

You need to escape `+` & `( and )` in sed without extended regex flag (`-r OR -E`).

WIth `-r` it will be:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+).*/\1/g' <<< "$s"
12345
```

**UPDATE:** You don't really need any external utility for this as you can do this in BASH itself using its regex capabilities:

```
[[ "$s*" =~ ^([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
12345
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, using `sed -r 's/([0-9]+).*/\1/g' <<< "$s"` will yield me `abcd 12345`

I am unsure as to how it's capturing `abcd`

Comment: `sed -r 's/([0-9]+).*/\1/g' <<< "$s"` gives me `12345`

Comment: Can you please explain the idea behind using a here string? As far as I understand, that just runs the `sed` expression on the contents of the Bash variable `s`, which does not seem helpful.

Comment: Let me ask first why do you think it is not helpful? For one using here-string prevents sub-shell creation.

Comment: This is the only way it would work for me:
`s="abcde 12345 67890testing"`
`[[ $s =~ ([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Answer (score 0):

since others already provided the solution with sed, grep, here is the awk code:

```
echo "abcde 12345 67890testing"|awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[0-9]+$/) print $i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cut command is simpler

```
echo "abcde 12345 67890testing" | cut -d' ' -f2
```